# Is it correct to write "I saw her hang her head crying"

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, run-on-sentences

I came across a video about Gif with sound on YouTube. I had not seen any videos of this kind before. But the video was very interesting and I learned a new idiom from an embedded song from Scissor Sisters in the video.

According to the Cambridge online dictionary, **hang one's head** means to be ​ashamed or ​unhappy.
In my diary, I have written this sentence,

> I saw her crying alone in the school lavatory on second floor yesterday.

Now I want to rewrite it this way, but I don't know whether it is correct:

> I saw her **hang her head** crying alone in the school lavatory on second floor yesterday.

Comment: There's an interesting timing problem with your rewrite.  Normally I would say "I saw her hang her head and start to cry" or "I saw her crying alone with her head hung low". I'll have to think about how to explain why.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but it should be *on the second floor*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be my opinion only, but for what it's worth, here goes:

"Hang her head" is a dated expression that comes across as awfully bookish, and/or impossibly mawkish, today. You should therefore use it sparingly and not try to blend it with contemporary phrases, least of all idiomatic ones.

"I saw her hang her head in shame. She was alone in the school lavatory on the second floor, crying quietly."

Comment: Famous lyrics with this phrase: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZYjc57V55U

Comment: Also this more modern song https://youtu.be/MNE-HUxNjds Hanging your head is not as dated as this answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, but cumbersome. Having two phrases describing what you saw ("crying alone" and "hanging her head") makes the sentence difficult to decipher. Better to split it up as @Ricky suggests.

I don't agree with @Ricky that the phrase is dated, although it's not exactly fashionable either: but perhaps that's because no-one has any shame nowadays.